# Parsing XML response in PHP (and/or Zend Framework)

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, parsing

I am using the Zend Framework and using `Zend_Http_Client` to make a POST request to a third party API.

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://api.com');
$client->setParameterPost(array(
    'param1' => 'value'
));
$response = $client->request('POST');
echo $response->getBody();
```

This API returns an XML document as its response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<registration>
    <id>12345</id>
</registration>
```

How can I turn the response into something I can work with?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513010/php-xml-parsing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I find the easiest way is to use SimpleXml

`$data = simplexml_load_string($response->getBody());`

Then, to get the ID, you can use

`$id = (string) $data->registration->id;`

Comment: simplexml_load_string often segfaults as of this time. It seems unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

for xml file from url, you can use below code.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('any url here');

echo $xml->id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it XMLRPC? Look into `Zend_XmlRpc`. 
Otherwise: see Pekka's link in the comment on the Question, or use `Zend_Config_Xml` (not really what its intended for, though)