# How to process raw XML page

Tags: php, html, xml, parsing

I am working on the development of a user interface and wondered what I can do to store or use an XML document that is returned based on a URL request.

I want to be able to place elements of this into my PHP page.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP XML Parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513010/php-xml-parsing)

Answer (score 0):

Check some examples of how to parse the XML with JS : http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_examples.asp

Here is an example of how to parse XML with PHP : http://www.kirupa.com/web/xml_php_parse_beginner.htm

Here is a SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510995/parse-xml-response-with-jquery) about parsing XML with jQuery

Comment: this is not from a file but instead from xml dynamically generated.

Comment: It is the same, I guess. When You read from a file, You grab it and then parse. Here is the same situation, only that You don't have to read the file. - You can still parse it with JS or PHP the same way.