# Assign variables to values from xml

Tags: php, xml, parsing

My XML file is:

```
<hotels xmlns="">
  <hotels>
    <hotel>
      <noofrooms>10</noofrooms>
      <website></website>
      <imageref>oias-sunset-2.jpg|villas-agios-nikolaos-1.jpg|villas-agios-nikolaos-24.jpg|villas-agios-nikolaos-41.jpg</imageref>
      <descr>blah blah blah</descr>
      <hotelid>119</hotelid>
    </hotel>
</hotels>
```

I want to assign each imageref a variable:

```
$image1 = "oias-sunset-2.jpg";
$image2 = "villas-agios-nikolaos-1.jpg";
.............
```

Comment: load whole xml file (e.g. `simplexml_load_file`) and then use `explode('|', $element)` on imageref element

Comment: Search is your friend :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513010/php-xml-parsing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121933/parsing-xml-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your xml was valid you could use (as suggested in comments):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($path_to_file);
$images = explode('|', $xml->hotel->imageref);
```

To see what you have now you can use:

```
print_r($images);
```

See http://php.net/simplexml_load_file

Answer (score 0):

You an use SimpleXML to parse your file and then the explode function to split it into your variables.

```
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($yoursqlstring);
foreach($doc->hotel as $hotel){
    $refs = explode('|',$hotel->imageref);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$images[] = '';
$xmlString = 'your xml';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
foreach ($xml->hotels->hotel->imageref as $img_urls) {
 $images[] = $img_urls;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($yoursqlstring);
foreach($doc->hotel as $hotel){
    $image_array = explode('|', $hotel->imageref);
    foreach($image_array as $k => $img)
        $image[$k+1] = $img;
}
```

Now you can access the images by

```
echo $image[1];
echo $image[2];
.
.
.
```